# Nginx Subdomain/Staging Server conflicting server name

Tags: nginx, server, subdomain, conflict

Hi I am trying to configure a server and its subdomain with nginx but the nginx shows conflicting servername. I have tried these settings. Can anyone suggest how can i configure subdomain with nginx?
I am getting error:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name ":" on 0.0.0.0:3000, ignored

server{
listen 3000;
server_name : www.website.com website.com;
......
}
server{
listen 3000;
server_name : www.staging.website.com staging.website.com;
......
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
server{
listen 3000;
server_name www.website.com website.com;
......
}
server{
listen 3000;
server_name www.staging.website.com staging.website.com;
......
}
```

without colon.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I wasted almost 2 hours for this stupidity.